# How to check for a value in a list of tuples?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
l = [(10,'bat'), (50,'ball'), (100,'goal')]
```

and I want to check if `100` is in any of the tuples. And if it is there I need to remove its value which is '`goal`'.

How can I do this?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to filter out the tuple:

```
l = [t for t in l if t[0] != 100]
```

If you want/have to do this with multiple values, you can create a set of them:

```
exclude = set(100, 30, 20)
l = [t for t in l if t[0] not in exclude]
```

Answer (score 0):

Checks for 100 in any column and removes 100 from tuple.

```
l = [(10,'bat'), (50,'ball'), (100,'goal')]
for i, row in enumerate(l[:]):
    if any(col == 100 for col in row):
        new_row = filter(lambda col: col != 100, row)
        l[i] = new_row

print l
```